# Pinging/ssh-ing into just trunk interface. How is it done?

Tags: switch, vlan, trunk, ssh, management

I'm a junior network technician and I was tasked at work to do a switch upgrade. The most important part of this task is to set up SSH so we can at least get into the switch remotely configure once shipped out to remote office.

On the existing switch there is a management VLAN set to 99 and when I run show vlan I see that this VLAN does not have a port associated with it.

Usually when I set up SSH I associate IP address to VLAN, and then I associate a port to said VLAN with management IP. Then when I run show VLAN I will see management VLAN with associated port to the right.

In the case of the switch I am trying to duplicate, when I run show vlan I see VLAN 99 Management does not have port associated with it. My networking manager said something about not being a need to associate interface with vlan, and to just use the trunk port to ssh.

How is this accomplished? With the original switch, I'm able to ping and ssh the trunk port with the management IP address. When I try to do the same thing on the switch I'm configuring I do not get a response to ping let alone SSH.

My whole objective here is to set up a management interface with management IP address without explicit associated trunk interface with IP address like I would normally do with an access port.

Just to keep things simple, I'm trying to get this to work with just a switch and management workstation at the moment.

Could someone please tell me how I can ping/ssh management IP address just via the trunk port (and not have to specify specific ports?)? Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: What is the switch model and configuration?

Comment: We need to see your configuration to be sure what you're missing.  "Show VLAN" . does not show which VLANs are forwarding on trunk ports.  If VLAN 99 has an IP address, and the interface VLAN 99 is up, you can ssh to that address if you are trunking that VLAN to another switch that is the source of your ping or ssh.

Comment: Edit your question to include your configuration.  A simple digram would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some devices, a *trunk port* implicitly encompasses all VLANs defined on the device, ie. a trunk port automatically becomes a member of each VLAN, unless configured otherwise.

On other devices, there are no global trunk ports and each port's VLAN membership has to be either *explicitly* configured or learned through a registration protocol e.g. MVRP or GVRP.

You'll need to check the manual for a given device's definition of *trunk port* or general VLAN trunking and how VLAN membership works.